# Database lock wait timeout exceeded (REST API)

Tags: rest, api, magento2

I've the error

> "Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400 - {"message":"Database lock wait timeout exceeded","code":1205}"

What processes (magento core) occur during import the product catalog and how can they be managed?

```
magento 2.2.2
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Lock wait timeout is very a frequent problem. First, check your MySQL configuration on my.cnf, especially check "wait timeout" parameter - probably you must increase the value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Done it in the beginning. wait_timeout=28800. It seems, that's not the reason. According MyTop utility much time takes the process of full search reindexing (up to 10 min) it causes timeouts then MySQL unfreezes but REST API doesn't respond already! Could you recomend something?
WBR, Roman

Comment: I've switched off CRON in advaced config (system_config/edit/section/system) by intering 10080 in all fields with no CRON in server configs but still I've got queries to reindex fullsearch during inport the catalog! How to disable CRON completely?

Comment: Roman If you want to disable cron you must delete all records in cron. If you have cpanel or other admin server dashboard you must change in them. If you have VPS'a you must delete all records in shell. BTW. change max_allowed_packet value maybe have you problem with fluent information.

Comment: Karol, I've installed clear distributive Debian which goes without any configuration of CRON by default. BUT despite this I get queries of reindex fulltext search during import tha catalog! How can I disable them completly?

Comment: You must set all index to manual save. BTW.  have you set flat table on configuration?

Comment: What do you mean "flat table". Where I should do this?

Comment: Find this: http://static.xpertdeveloper.com/uploads/2011/08/Enable_Flat_database_model_in_magento-e1313235124360.png